# Is it always the best idea to write a function for anything that needs to repeat twice?

Tags: python, function, coding-style

Myself, I can't wait to write a function when I need to do something more than twice. But when it comes to things that only appear twice, it's a bit more tricky.

For code that needs more than two lines, I'll write a function. But when facing things like:

```
print ("Hi, Tom")
print ("Hi, Mary")
```

I'm hesitant to write:

```
def greeting(name):
    print ("Hi, " + name)

greeting('Tom')
greeting('Mary')
```

The second one seems too much, doesn't it?

---

But what if we have:

```
for name in vip_list:
    print (name)
for name in guest_list:
    print (name)
```

And here is the alternative:

```
def print_name(name_list):
    for name in name_list:
        print (name)

print_name(vip_list)
print_name(guest_list)
```

Things become tricky, no? It's hard to decide now.

What's your opinion about this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right to be hesitant to define functions in these cases, because really what you want is to abstract the *repetition*, not the thing being repeated.

For your first example,

```
for name in "Tom", "Mary":
    print("Hi, %s" % (name,))
```

For your second,

```
for lst in vip_list, guest_list:
    for name in lst:
        print(name)
```

or, depending on the context, something like this might be more expressive:

```
for name in itertools.chain(vip_list, guest_list):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Thank you, for your response. As I have learned that repetitions should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about it being the best practice, but I have been doing stuff like this with some generic functions that I have used in the past.

```
def printf(string, *args, **kwargs):
    print(string % args, **kwargs)
```

usage, where it is single:

```
printf("Hi %s", x1)
```

and usage, where x is an array (at a push).

```
printf("Hi %s\n" * len(names), *names, end="")
```

...

```
for names in names_list:
    printf("Hi %s\n" * len(names), *names, end="")
```

I'm not sure printing is a good example. Say for instance loading a JSON file:

```
def load_json(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

I might tempted to do this even if it was only used once. And i guess this goes back to what a previous poster mentioned about abstraction.